# I want to set my layout background as my profile image .. how to do this like this app called vero does

Tags: android, ios

[image]

you can see this image I want profile image to set as my layout background

Comment: Show your effort first.

Comment: then set it, why you can't?

Comment: so whats the issue? use the image as background and on some layout apply `alpha`

Comment: where is code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this library https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry

you have to do this,

```
Blurry.with(context)
.radius(10)
.sampling(8)
.color(Color.argb(66, 255, 255, 0))
.async()
.onto(parentView);
```